# Url of upload button in twitter

Tags: java, html, url, twitter, url-rewriting

am wondering if there a specific URL for twitter to upload files like videos ,I want a URL copy paste on the browser to directly ask me to upload files to twitter

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload)

Comment: iv read this its not working 
https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json

Comment: What exactly is "not working" What have you tried? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please read the question again, i want a url that directly ask me to upload files to twitter studio "videos"..

Comment: for example, if i want to tweet ...https://twitter.com/intent/tweet

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).